# How to use matchNr from extractor element with Random?

Tags: jmeter

I am using a XPath extractor inside a Loop Controller and have the issue that I can't use the **matchNr** of the extractor.

[image]

If I am using Counter instead of Random Variable I can access the matchNr.
I have tried to build it with a While and Loop Controller without success.

How to add some random there?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, but I don't like it:

[image]

The second Loop Controller just loop for one time. The **FloatGlassPackage Random (Counter)** uses the `__Random` function like `${__Random(1,${number_matchNr},packageNumber)}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one:

```
${__V(number_${number_matchNr})}
```

As per [__V() function documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V):

> For example, if one has variables A1,A2 and N=1:
>
> ${A1} - works OK
>
> ${A${N}} - does not work (nested variable reference)
>
> ${__V(A${N})} - works OK. A${N} becomes A1, and the __V function returns the value of A1

Also it worth checking out [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series, they clarify some use cases which aren't very obvious.